# SSH and -bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory Ubuntu , rails , Passenger, redis , sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, nginx, swap, bad-gateway

I'm running a rails app (dev server) with passenger in Amazon AWS with t2.micro instance. But i'm getting `-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory` error constantly.

I'm running redis server on it with 50 sidekiq concurrency. Normally sites runs fine but when i start 2-3 sidekiq process simultaneously do do some batch process. The site take take time to redirect and eventylly crash with

```
502 Bad Gateway 
nginx/1.10.0
```

Then i have to nginx restart every to to get the site running again. This is my dev server so i don't want to put more financial resources for upgrading to t2.small (as of now, this is our last option) as this is dev servre and will be using twice in 15 days. Is there any way i can solve this otherwise? Previously i had same 120 concurrency as production but then i changed to 50. That help a bit but still memory problems.

here are few stats with `htop`

[image]

This stats are while the server is idle. But when i run few task with sidekiq it crashing with 502.

I check few [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985229/ssh-and-bash-fork-cannot-allocate-memory-vps-ubuntu) suggesting swap memory but not sure this is preferable with t2.micro. Is this advisable for this server  setup. Here in pic you can see i don't swap memory. Is it okay yo add swap memory to tackle this issue or there is any other better option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your server has a lack of memory, to fix it:

- or: buy more operative memory
- or: [mount a swap](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Then try again

Comment: Thanks @itsnikolay , I'll tied the swap memory steps and it worked fine. Now i'm able to share the load of RAM with swap memory and the system is not failing.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, redis used 2.5G memory, the server has 4.5G in total, and 3G is used. 
1.5G free.

and Redis kept throwing this error.

solution:

1. add `vm.overcommit_memory=1` to file: `/etc/sysctl.conf`
2. `sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf`

refer to: [redis bgsave failed because fork Cannot allocate memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11752544/redis-bgsave-failed-because-fork-cannot-allocate-memory)